# How to design search for [location, title, time-range]

Tags: database, elasticsearch, cassandra, lucene

Trying to build an distributed application which needs to support search by location , title and time-range.

Queries will be read 80% and write 20%.

I am thinking of adding secondary indexes for the above items.

Any other suggestion? I am new to distributed field, so please forgive if this is very descriptive question/broad question.

Please provide hints/wiki/doc/links for me to dig further if this is a very broad question.

Also, how can I make things faster by adding some system memory across few machines and keep things in memory? I have 5 machines across geos.

Comment: Elasticsearch supports your use case "needs to support search by location , title and time-range.". 

Elasticsearch doesnt have secondary index.(Probably you are referring  to cassandra)

Comment: by search, do you mean exact match, like get with identifiers ? or more like a full text search ... ? 
Cassandra secondary index is bad idea in most cases.

Comment: For ex :
Location: All items from a city

title: all items which match/contain this in its title.(like partial word search..)
time range search: items between date1 and date2
How to index to optimize all queries?